# how to sum the time grouped by individual day in Sql-server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table with id, play, starttime and endtime. I want to find the total play time per day. I think the query will be similar as the following but I am sure it is not right. It will be also very convenient if i get 0 when no game is played but if it is difficult I dont mind.

```
Select 
id, 
play,
date,
CASE
    WHEN datediff(day, starttime, endtime) = 0 then sum(totaltime)
END as TimePerDay
from cte where starttime >= '2015-05-30 17:11:34.000'
group by id, playtime, starttime, endtime
```

I am looking for

```
id | play    | Date        | totaltime
1  | hockey  | 05/06/2015  | 0
2  | hockey  | 04/06/2015  | 0
3  | hockey  | 03/06/2015  | 230
4  | hockey  | 02/06/2015  | 10
5  | hockey  | 01/06/2015  | 120
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
Select play, cast(starttime as date) as date,
       SUM(datediff(MINUTE, endtime, starttime)) as TimePerDay
from cte
where starttime >= '2015-05-30 17:11:34.000'
group by play, cast(starttime as date)

union


SELECT 'hockey', DATEADD(DAY,number+1,(select min(starttime) from cte)) as date, 0 as TimePerDay
                FROM master..spt_values
                WHERE type = 'P'
                AND DATEADD(DAY,number+1,(select min(starttime) from cte)) < (select max(starttime) from cte)
                and CAST(DATEADD(DAY,number+1,(select min(starttime) from cte)) as date) not in (select cast(starttime as date) from cte)
```

For Express Version :

```
DECLARE @startDate date = (select min(starttime) from cte)
DECLARE @endDate date = (select max(starttime) from cte)


;WITH dates(Date) AS 
(
    SELECT @startdate as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,[Date])
    FROM dates 
    WHERE DATE < @enddate
)
Select play, cast(starttime as date) as date,
       SUM(datediff(MINUTE, endtime, starttime)) as TimePerDay
from cte
where starttime >= '2015-05-30 17:11:34.000'
group by play, cast(starttime as date)

union 

SELECT 'hockey' as play, Date, 0 as TimePerDay
FROM dates
where Date not in (select cast(starttime as date) from cte)
```

Comment: Reference to database and/or server name in 'master..spt_values' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Comment: Which version you are using ?

Comment: So if I remove the union part, it is working fine. I think the union part is to show each day and 0 if no game played. is it?

Comment: Yes.. @Asbat it is for that

Comment: What is the error you are getting in last union part ?

Comment: I am already using cte and therefore it is giving error on appending. I am new to sql-server. Any idea how to avoid it.

Comment: i didnt get you, can you show your complete query (with cte)

Comment: Ok, I got it. I was trying to show the data in asp.net column chart and it is wise enough to show empty on the missing dates. so I am happy with your half answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi again, Can you please have a look of my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160089/how-to-extend-the-query-to-add-0-in-the-cell-when-no-activity-is-performed . I am facing the same problem.