# How to extend the query to add 0 in the cell when no activity is performed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query, it is working fine to show the cricket time played per day. All I need is to show 0 when no cricket is played. At the moment it is skipping those dates. For more reference please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663600/how-to-sum-the-time-grouped-by-individual-day-in-sql-server).

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT email, last_update, activity, starttime, endtime, duration as [Totaltime] from users 
WHERE activity='cricket' and email='abc'
GROUP BY email, activity, duration, starttime, endtime, last_update
)
Select activity, cast(starttime as date) as date,
SUM(datediff(second, starttime, endtime))/60.0 as TimePerDay
from cte
where starttime >= dateadd(day, -15, last_update)
group by activity, cast(starttime as date)
```

current output of the query is

```
activity | date        | TimePerDay
cricket  | 2015-06-16  | 80.01
cricket  | 2015-06-17  | 90.01
cricket  | 2015-06-18  | 120.01
cricket  | 2015-06-22  | 10.01
```

The desired output is

```
activity | date        | TimePerDay
cricket  | 2015-06-16  | 80.01
cricket  | 2015-06-17  | 90.01
cricket  | 2015-06-18  | 120.01
cricket  | 2015-06-19  | 0
cricket  | 2015-06-20  | 0
cricket  | 2015-06-21  | 0
cricket  | 2015-06-22  | 10.01
```

Comment: Is last_update the same for every row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try this also :- (this could only for one particular activity)

```
Set Nocount On;

Declare  @MinDate   Date
        ,@MaxDate   Date

Declare @test Table
(
     activity       Varchar(100)
    ,date           Date
    ,TimePerDay     Decimal(5,2)
)

Declare @result Table
(
     activity       Varchar(100)
    ,date           Date
    ,TimePerDay     Decimal(5,2) Default 0
)

;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT   email
            ,last_update
            ,activity
            ,starttime
            ,endtime
            ,duration As Totaltime 
    From    users With (Nolock)
    WHERE   activity ='cricket' 
            And email = 'abc'
    GROUP BY email
            ,activity
            ,duration
            ,starttime
            ,endtime
            ,last_update
)

Insert Into @test(activity,date,TimePerDay)
Select   activity
        ,Cast(starttime as date) As date
        ,SUM(datediff(second, starttime, endtime))/60.0 As TimePerDay
From    cte With (Nolock)
where   starttime >= dateadd(day, -15, last_update)
group by activity
        ,cast(starttime as date)

Select   @MinDate = Min(Date)
        ,@MaxDate = Max(Date)
From    @test

;With AllDates As
(
    Select   @MinDate As xDate
    From    @test As t1
    Where   t1.date = @MinDate

    Union All

    Select  Dateadd(Day, 1, xDate)
    From    AllDates As ad
    Where   ad.xDate < @MaxDate
)
```

**One way is :-** (left join)

```
Select  'cricket' As activity
        ,ad.xDate
        ,Isnull(t.TimePerDay,0) As TimePerDay
From    AllDates As ad With (Nolock)
        Left Join @test As t On ad.xDate = t.date
```

**another way is :-** (insert with all dates and update)

```
    Insert Into @result(activity,date)
Select  'cricket'
        ,ad.xDate
From    AllDates As ad With (Nolock)

Update  t
Set     t.TimePerDay = t1.TimePerDay
From    @result As t
        Join @test As t1 On t.date = t1.date

Select  *
From    @result As r
```

**output**

[image]

**Update**

```
Declare  @MinDate   Date
        ,@MaxDate   Date

Select   @MaxDate = Getdate()
        ,@MinDate = Dateadd(Day, -14, @MaxDate)

;With AllDates As
(
    Select   @MinDate As xDate

    Union All

    Select  Dateadd(Day, 1, xDate)
    From    AllDates As ad
    Where   ad.xDate < @MaxDate
)

Select   @activity As activity                      ---- @activity (your stored procedure parameter)
        ,ad.xDate
        ,Isnull(t.TimePerDay,0) As TimePerDay
From    AllDates As ad With (Nolock)
        Left Join @test As t On ad.xDate = t.date
```

Comment: Both the methods work like a chart. It takes only 6 seconds to execute and get the results. I selected option1.

Comment: BTW will it work if I make it a procedure and pass the value of email by variable to that procedure??

Comment: Yes, it will work, and if you have only one activity then only need to pass email by parameter, otherwise, you need to pass activity as well, as part of parameter of stored procedure. And if you follow the option 1 then don't create "result" table, it is for option 2.

Comment: I got into a small problem. In the case when I select hockey for which there is no instance in the database, I get blank table. I was expecting 0.00 for the last 15 days. Any suggestion??

Comment: Ohh! Sorry, its my mistake, I updates the code, kindly look into that update.

Comment: I have added 'update' just now, try with that one change in your stored procedure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82472/discussion-between-mihir-shah-and-asbat).

Answer (score 3):

**AS PREPARATION,** you need to generate a list of dates. There are multiple ways for that. One is a recursive CTE. For example, this one creates a list of the last 15 days:

```
with datelist ([date]) as 
(
    select dateadd(dd, -15, cast(getdate() as date)) as [date] -- 15 days back
    union all
    select dateadd(dd, 1, [date]) from datelist where dateadd(dd, 1, [date]) <= getdate()
)
select * from datelist option (maxrecursion 400)
```

**FOR THE FINAL SOLUTION,** you now need to create a `LEFT JOIN` between the `datelist` and with a subquery with your `user` table. 
An overall solution for your question therefore goes as follows.

I have also put everything together in a **SQLFiddle**: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36510/1

```
with datelist ([date]) as 
(
    select dateadd(dd, -15, cast(getdate() as date)) as [date] -- 15 days back
    union all
    select dateadd(dd, 1, [date]) from datelist where dateadd(dd, 1, [date]) <= getdate()
)
select 'cricket' as activity, 
       d.[date],
       coalesce(SUM(datediff(second, u.starttime, u.endtime)/60.0), 0)
            as TimePerDay      
from datelist d
     left join 
     (
          select [starttime], [endtime], cast(starttime as date) as [date]
          from [users]  
          where activity='cricket' and email='abc'
     ) u
     on d.[date] = u.[date]
group by d.[date]
option (maxrecursion 400)
```

So this query will give you the table for the cricket activity of the last 15 days of one specific user.

Comment: Can you please tell me what part of my query should go in the SELECT ... PUT YOUR QUERY HERE ... section in YOUR query. Is data a variable? can you assign a value to it to help me understanding. Thanks.

Comment: placing my whole query in the paranthesis gives me following error. Query is not happy with ; at the start of cte and the paranthesis before s in the third last line.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near ';'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 35
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: @Asbat I have now put everything together, including a SQLFiddle. You can directly copy-paste that into your project. It will definitively give you the desired activity table for one user. All the best!

Comment: Thanks, Your query is working fine but one issue is that it is taking 32 seconds to execute. I am looking which of the answers are most efficient one and after that I will select that one as answer.

Comment: @asbat very likely, you need to set an index on your table. then the query will boost.

Answer (score 2):

You need a list of dates.  The easiest way -- if you have data on each date, but just not for the `where` conditions -- is to use conditional aggregation:

```
Select activity, cast(starttime as date) as date,
       SUM(case when activity = 'cricket' and email = 'abc'
                then datediff(second, starttime, endtime))/60.0
                else 0
           end) as TimePerDay
from users
where starttime >= dateadd(day, -15, last_update)
group by activity, cast(starttime as date);
```

Otherwise, if the dates are not in the table, then you need a list of dates.  This can come from:

- A calendar table.
- A recursive CTE.
- An explicit list in the query.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near ')'. I am getting error in your part of code. it looks fine to me. Can you figure out ?

Comment: The output is still the same :( which means that I dont have a list of dates. Any suggestion on how to create the last 15 dates?

Comment: @Asbat . . . There are already other answers that provide alternative approaches.

Answer (score 2):

First You have to generate the Date series with a query like this:

```
-- Generate 15 past days name from now
set @n:=date(now() + interval 1 day);
select (select @n:= @n - interval 1 day) day_series from users  limit 15;
```

and then join select with date_series. for null values you can use COALESCE:

```
SELECT q2.day_series as days , COALESCE(TimePerDay, 0) as TPD from Your_select q1
right join (
    -- select date_series
) as q2
on q1.Timestamp = q2.day_series and ....
```

--- final Query based on my understanding from 1st query

```
set @n:=date(now() + interval 1 day);
SELECT activity
,cast(starttime AS DATE) AS q1_DATE
,COALESCE(SUM(datediff(second, starttime, endtime)) / 60.0, 0) AS TimePerDay
FROM (
    SELECT email
        ,last_update
        ,activity
        ,starttime
        ,endtime
        ,duration AS Totaltime
    FROM users
    WHERE activity = 'cricket'
        AND email = 'abc'
    GROUP BY email
        ,activity
        ,duration
        ,starttime
        ,endtime
        ,last_update
    ) q1
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT (
            SELECT @n: = @n - interval 1 day
            ) day_series
    FROM users limit 15
    ) q2 ON q1.q1_DATE = q2.day_series
WHERE starttime >= dateadd(day, - 15, last_update)
GROUP BY activity
    ,cast(starttime AS DATE);
```

Comment: Can you incorporate this into the above query because I am generating asp.net chart and I cant pass many arguments except email.

Comment: I think you have syntax error in above query! 
what is the dateadd()?!!
I don't know what you mean about "dateadd(day, -15, last_update)"

Comment: It gets the data for the last 15 days from the date of last update. I think it also truncates the time part from the date time because time part add complications in comparisons.

Comment: I got this error  
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ':'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 24
Must declare the scalar variable "@n".

Comment: That variable has declared in the 1st line (set @n:=date(now() + interval 1 day).

Comment: I copied and pasted your code but got same error. I am using sql server 2014 SSMS with the database in azure, if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT email, last_update, activity, starttime, endtime, duration as [Totaltime] from users 
WHERE activity='cricket' and email='abc'
GROUP BY email, activity, duration, starttime, endtime, last_update
)
select activity, cast(starttime as date) as date,
SUM(datediff(second, starttime, endtime))/60.0 as TimePerDay
into #tempcte
from CTE
--where starttime >= dateadd(day, -15, last_update)
group by activity, cast(starttime as date)

select * from #tempcte

DECLARE @startDate date = (select min([date]) from #tempcte)
DECLARE @endDate date = (select max([date]) from #tempcte)
;WITH dates(Date) AS 
(
    SELECT @startdate as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,dates.Date)
    FROM dates 
    WHERE dates.Date < @enddate --and dates.Date not in (select [date] from #tempcte)
)
--select * from dates
Select activity, [date], TimePerDay
from #tempcte
union
select 'cricket' activity, [Date] as Date, 0 as TimePerDay FROM dates where dates.Date not in (select [date] from #tempcte)

drop table #tempcte
```

Comment: Yea I need to revise.

Comment: Thanks for taking interest.

Comment: I have updated the query, Can you please check the output?

Comment: I got the error Msg 40510, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Statement 'SELECT INTO' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You can generate the missing dates in a union by using the existing CTE as a basis for Row_Number()

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT email, last_update, activity, starttime, endtime, duration as [Totaltime] from users 
WHERE activity='cricket' and email='abc'
GROUP BY email, activity, duration, starttime, endtime, last_update
)
Select activity, cast(starttime as date) as date,
SUM(datediff(second, starttime, endtime))/60.0 as TimePerDay
from cte
where starttime >= dateadd(day, -15, last_update)
group by activity, cast(starttime as date)
UNION ALL
Select 'cricket' activity, everyday.[date], 0
FROM 
(
    select top 1000 dateadd(day,row_number() OVER (order by starttime),(select cast(min(starttime) as date) from CTE)) [date]
    from CTE
) everyday
WHERE everyday.[date] NOT IN (SELECT cast(starttime as date) FROM CTE)
AND everyday.[date] < (SELECT cast(max(starttime) as date) from CTE)
ORDER BY date
```

Comment: I got error Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
Invalid column name 'starttime'.

Answer (score 2):

This is a long query but should give you what you need.. It will also work for multiple activities.

```
;
    WITH    CTE
            AS ( SELECT   email ,
                        last_update ,
                        activity ,
                        starttime ,
                        endtime ,
                        duration AS [Totaltime]
                FROM     users
                WHERE    activity = 'cricket'
                        AND email = 'abc'
                GROUP BY email ,
                        activity ,
                        duration ,
                        starttime ,
                        endtime ,
                        last_update
                ),
        cteSummary
            AS ( SELECT   activity ,
                        CAST(starttime AS DATE) AS date ,
                        SUM(DATEDIFF(second, starttime, endtime)) / 60.0 AS TimePerDay
                FROM     cte
                WHERE    starttime >= DATEADD(day, -15, last_update)
                GROUP BY activity ,
                        CAST(starttime AS DATE)
                ),
        cteDateRange
            AS ( SELECT   activity ,
                        MIN(date) AS MinDate ,
                        MAX(date) AS MaxDate
                FROM     cteSummary
                GROUP BY activity
                ),
        cteDateRecur
            AS ( SELECT   activity ,
                        CalDate = CONVERT(DATE, MinDate) ,
                        MaxDate
                FROM     cteDateRange
                UNION ALL
                SELECT   activity ,
                        CalDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, c.CalDate) ,
                       MaxDate
                FROM     cteDateRecur c
                WHERE    c.CalDate < c.MaxDate
                )
    SELECT  d.activity ,
            d.CalDate AS date ,
            ISNULL(s.TimePerDay, 0) AS TimePerDay
    FROM    cteDateRecur d
            LEFT JOIN cteSummary s ON d.CalDate = s.date
    OPTION  ( MAXRECURSION 0 )
```

Comment: I am getting error: Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: should be good now.  needed to add maxdate to cteDateRecur cte

Comment: Thanks but I got a different error this time. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 43
The multi-part identifier "a.TimePerDay" could not be bound.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Many thanks. One issue is that when I select hockey  for which there is no activity in the database, I get blank table. Ideally I would like to see 15 instances of dates and 0.00 for TimePerDay