# SQL Server select missing Dates in result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one table containing Employee Daily Attendance punchtime in space separated form.

EmployeePunch

```
EmpID    EmpName    Date          Time

1        ABC        2014-12-01    10:00 18:00
1        ABC        2014-12-02    09:50 17:50
1        ABC        2014-12-04    09:30 17:30
1        ABC        2014-12-07    10:00 18:00
1        ABC        2014-12-08    09:50 17:50
1        ABC        2014-12-10    09:30 17:30
```

Now I want to write a query for following output

```
EmpID    EmpName    Date          Time

1        ABC        2014-12-01    10:00 18:00
1        ABC        2014-12-02    09:50 17:50
1        ABC        2014-12-03    ABSENT
1        ABC        2014-12-04    09:30 17:30
1        ABC        2014-12-05    ABSENT
1        ABC        2014-12-06    ABSENT
1        ABC        2014-12-07    10:00 18:00
1        ABC        2014-12-08    09:50 17:50
1        ABC        2014-12-09    ABSENT
1        ABC        2014-12-10    09:30 17:30
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not about doing your work for you. Try http://www.freelancer.com

Comment: you can refer this, there are too many ways for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160089/how-to-extend-the-query-to-add-0-in-the-cell-when-no-activity-is-performed/31218759#31218759

Comment: *Now I want to write a query for following output* - good plan, when you've done that and you're still having trouble, tell us what trouble you're having.  As @Amit says, we're not here to do the work for you, we're here to figure out what is wrong with what you've tried

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql server displaying missing dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329722/sql-server-displaying-missing-dates)

Answer (score 0):

First define CTE to generate missing records:

```
WITH dates AS (
SELECT DISTINCT EmpId, EmpName, '2014-12-01' AS Date, 'ABSENT' AS Time
FROM EmployeePunch
UNION
SELECT EmpId, EmpName, DATEADD(DAY, 1, Date), 'ABSENT'
FROM dates
WHERE Date < DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, '2014-12-01')))
SELECT * FROM dates
```

In the next step replace the last line with:

```
SELECT * FROM EmployeePunch
UNION ALL
SELECT d.* FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN EmployeePunch e
ON e.EmpId = d.EmpId AND e.Date = d.Date
WHERE e.Time IS NULL
```

The missing rows are the outerjoined ones.

Answer (score 0):

Without CTE:

```
select ep1.EmpId, ep1.EmpName, a.Date, ISNULL(ep2.Time, 'ABSENT') as Time
from (
    select DATEADD(day, a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a), CAST('2014-12-01' /*begin date*/ AS DATE)) as Date
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
) a cross apply (select distinct EmpId, EmpName from EmployeePunch) ep1 --on a.Date = f.Date
left join EmployeePunch ep2 on ep2.Date = a.Date and ep2.EmpId = ep1.EmpId
where a.Date <= '2014-12-10' and ep1.EmpId is not null
```

Be aware about the maximal allowed range - 1000 days, but it can be extended if necessary

Comment: Other generator: `select x from (select 0,1,2,3) unpivot (x for y in ([0],[1],[2],[3]))`, 4x cross join and the number is 4*(4*(4*(4*x4+x3)+x2)+x1)+x0, this is range 0-1023

Comment: btw. repeated SELECT statements are good candidates for WITH clause