# How to change the query to give last 15 weeks of data instead of last 15 days from the SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

The following query gives playing time of the users from the database on daily basis for the last 15 days. It adds 0 if no game is played. Now I want to get the data of playing time on weekly basis and 0 if no game is played in the whole week. So I want the query to give the last 15 weeks of data.

Here is the daily query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetPlayingTimeOfthepeoplesPerDay] @email NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @MinDate DATE
        ,@MaxDate DATE
        ,@LastXDays INT

    SELECT @LastXDays = - 15

    SELECT @MaxDate = peoples.l_update
    FROM peoples
    WHERE peoples.email = @email

    DECLARE @test TABLE (
        quantity VARCHAR(100)
        ,DATE DATE
        ,TimePerDay DECIMAL(5, 2)
        );

    WITH CTE
    AS (
        SELECT peoples.email
            ,peoples.l_update
            ,act.quantity
            ,act.starttime
            ,act.endtime
            ,act.duration AS [Totaltime]
        FROM peoples
        INNER JOIN MPeoples ON peoples.Id = MPeoples.parent_id
        INNER JOIN slines ON MPeoples.id = slines.movesuser_id
        INNER JOIN seg ON slines.id = seg.sline_id
        INNER JOIN act ON seg.id = act.seg_id
        WHERE act.quantity = 'playing'
            AND (peoples.email = @email)
        GROUP BY peoples.email
            ,act.quantity
            ,act.duration
            ,act.starttime
            ,act.endtime
            ,peoples.l_update
        )
    INSERT INTO @test (
        quantity
        ,DATE
        ,TimePerDay
        )
    SELECT quantity
        ,Cast(starttime AS DATE) AS DATE
        ,SUM(datediff(second, starttime, endtime)) / 60.0 AS TimePerDay
    FROM cte WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE starttime >= dateadd(day, @LastXDays, l_update)
    GROUP BY quantity
        ,cast(starttime AS DATE)

    SELECT @MaxDate = @MaxDate
        ,@MinDate = dateadd(day, (@LastXDays + 1), @MaxDate);

    WITH AllDates
    AS (
        SELECT @MinDate AS xDate

        UNION ALL

        SELECT Dateadd(Day, 1, xDate)
        FROM AllDates AS ad
        WHERE ad.xDate < @MaxDate
        )
    SELECT 'playing' AS quantity
        ,ad.xDate
        ,Isnull(t.TimePerDay, 0) AS TimePerDay
    FROM AllDates AS ad WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN @test AS t ON ad.xDate = t.DATE
END
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do here. Maybe as simple as chaning your DATEADD functions to week instead of day? I have to ask...why in the world are you using a NOLOCK hint on your cte???

Comment: Thats what I was thinking too, I will give it a try. Here is the guy who helped me achieving this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160089/how-to-extend-the-query-to-add-0-in-the-cell-when-no-activity-is-performed

Comment: So you already have an answer? Or is that where the NOLOCK came from? Do you understand what that hint does? If not, then why are you using it? At this point I don't know if you need help here or not. If you do, you need to explain it more clearly. If not, then congratulations.

Comment: actually I do need help. I want to change the above query so that it gives the data of last 15 weeks. At the moment it is giving the last 15 days. I am not looking into nolock at the moment

Comment: Then as I said previously, change the DATEDIFF to week instead of day. And do yourself a favor by getting rid of those NOLOCK hints. They serve no purpose at all.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `DATEADD` from day to week.  Hence, two changes:

`dateadd(week, @LastXDays, l_update)`

and

`dateadd(week, (@LastXDays + 1), @MaxDate)`

In this case, I would also rename the `@LastXDays` variable to `@LastXWeeks`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetPlayingTimeOfthepeoplesPerDay] @email NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @MinDate DATE
        ,@MaxDate DATE
        ,@LastXDays INT

    SELECT @LastXWeeks = - 15

    SELECT @MaxDate = peoples.l_update
    FROM peoples
    WHERE peoples.email = @email

    DECLARE @test TABLE (
        quantity VARCHAR(100)
        ,DATE DATE
        ,TimePerDay DECIMAL(5, 2)
        );

    WITH CTE
    AS (
        SELECT peoples.email
            ,peoples.l_update
            ,act.quantity
            ,act.starttime
            ,act.endtime
            ,act.duration AS [Totaltime]
        FROM peoples
        INNER JOIN MPeoples ON peoples.Id = MPeoples.parent_id
        INNER JOIN slines ON MPeoples.id = slines.movesuser_id
        INNER JOIN seg ON slines.id = seg.sline_id
        INNER JOIN act ON seg.id = act.seg_id
        WHERE act.quantity = 'playing'
            AND (peoples.email = @email)
        GROUP BY peoples.email
            ,act.quantity
            ,act.duration
            ,act.starttime
            ,act.endtime
            ,peoples.l_update
        )
    INSERT INTO @test (
        quantity
        ,DATE
        ,TimePerDay
        )
    SELECT quantity
        ,Cast(starttime AS DATE) AS DATE
        ,SUM(datediff(second, starttime, endtime)) / 60.0 AS TimePerDay
    FROM cte WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE starttime >= dateadd(week, @LastXWeeks, l_update)
    GROUP BY quantity
        ,cast(starttime AS DATE)

    SELECT @MaxDate = @MaxDate
        ,@MinDate = dateadd(week, (@LastXWeeks + 1), @MaxDate);

    WITH AllDates
    AS (
        SELECT @MinDate AS xDate

        UNION ALL

        SELECT Dateadd(Day, 7, xDate)
        FROM AllDates AS ad
        WHERE ad.xDate < @MaxDate
        )
    SELECT 'playing' AS quantity
        ,ad.xDate
        ,Isnull(t.TimePerDay, 0) AS TimePerDay
    FROM AllDates AS ad WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN @test AS t ON ad.xDate = t.DATE
END
```

Also, a piece of advice: don't use query hints (`NOLOCK`) if you do not understand their use. In this case, using `NOLOCK` can have disastrous effects on your results.

Here are a few articles which you should read before deciding if you are going to keep using `NOLOCK` or not.

[Understanding the SQL Server NOLOCK hint](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2470/understanding-the-sql-server-nolock-hint/)

[Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Comment: There is one more dateadd method at the end, however it is not working as required. It is not summing the values of 7 days playing time.

Comment: @Asbat How about now?

Comment: Can I change  Dateadd(Day, 7, xDate) to Dateadd(week, 7, xDate) or not?

Comment: It is still not giving the desired result. I will give it try. I will update you. time to catch the bus. Thanks

Comment: SUM(datediff(second, starttime, endtime)) / 60.0 AS TimePerDay This statement in the query is adding per day playing. I want per week playing. Any idea?