# How to convert the following query to give sum per week

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

This is part of a long query which compute the total time per day. I want to change it to give me the total time per week. Any idea? To check the long query click [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859135/how-to-change-the-query-to-give-last-15-weeks-of-data-instead-of-last-15-days-fr)

```
INSERT INTO @test (
    activity
    ,DATE
    ,TimePerDay
    )
SELECT activity
    ,Cast(starttime AS DATE) AS DATE
    ,SUM(datediff(second, starttime, endtime)) / 60.0 AS TimePerDay
FROM cte WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE starttime >= dateadd(week, @LastXWeeks, last_update)
GROUP BY activity
    ,cast(starttime AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it for example this way:

```
SELECT activity
    ,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,Cast(starttime AS DATE)), 0) AS Week
    ,SUM(datediff(second, starttime, endtime)) / 60.0 AS TimePerDay
FROM cte WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE starttime >= dateadd(week, @LastXWeeks, last_update)
GROUP BY activity
    ,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,Cast(starttime AS DATE)), 0)
```

You might need to adjust the code depending on what day your week actually starts on. This works on Monday - Sunday.

Comment: Also, I hope you know all the problems NOLOCK can cause if you use it.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I change the week start day?

Comment: The zeros in the formula are date 'zero' which is 1.1.1900, which happens to be Monday. To change the day you'll have to replace those with another day, for example for Sunday you can use DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,'19950101',Cast(starttime AS DATE)), '19950101') since 1.1.1995 was Sunday.